# How to configure custom error page on Struts2?

Tags: struts2, custom-error-pages

I am using the following code to show a common error page whenever an exception is thrown.

I have two questions. First question is how to configure it in a way to support all types of the exceptions? 
The other question is how to register the type of exception thrown in database for future maintenance? I know I can save them into database after catching them but how about exceptions such as `antlr` versioning exception that are not catch by back-end and will be thrown through front-end ?

```
   <global-results>
       <result name="cuerror">error.jsp</result>
   </global-results>

   <global-exception-mappings>
       <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="cuserror"/>
   </global-exception-mappings>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *all types* of exceptions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Exceptions to declare/handle in struts xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726425/which-exceptions-to-declare-handle-in-struts-xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all errors try **java.lang.Throwable** exception.

For database exception I suggest you declare new exceptions so catch database exceptions and throw you defined new exceptions, there you can decide the type of exception by new exception which is thrown

I do not see any reason for this, I think the database exception and its message is sufficient for maintenance.